# Do you still get items you don't actively pick up in Online Vendetta?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

In ME: Shadow of War, if you kill an enemy during an Online Vendetta and they drop an item (gem most probably), do you get that if you don't go and pick it up yourself?  E.g. if you used a Ranged attack?